# Can't pass an IPC message to a browserwindow

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm messing around with electron, one of the things i'm trying to do is monitor a directory for file changes, and send the full path of the file that changed to a browser window via IPC to a renderer. I know the file watcher is working since it's logging to the console, but the path never makes it to the browserwindow.

Putting logging lines in the renderer never log, and remote debugging and stepping through the code, i can see it never fires off to the renderer.

Any idea? I'm new to this javascript stuff so it's probably something simple i'm missing. Thanks in advance!

**main.js:**

```
const electron = require('electron')
const app = electron.app
const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow
const ipc = electron.ipcMain
const watchfiles = require('./watchfiles')
const windows = []

app.on('ready', _ => {
    [1].forEach(_ => {   
        let win = new BrowserWindow({
            height: 400,
            width: 400
    })

    win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/watchfiles.html`)


    win.on('closed', _ => {
    mainWindow = null
})
    windows.push(win)
})
})

ipc.on('filewatch-start', _ => {
    //Log
    console.log('Filewatch started')
    watchfiles(fullPath => {
        windows.forEach(win => {
            win.webContents.send('changedfiles', fullPath)
        })
    })
})
```

**renderer.js:**

```
const electron = require('electron')

const ipc = electron.ipcRenderer

document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', _ =>{
    ipc.send('filewatch-start')
})

ipc.on('changedfiles', (event, message) => {
document.getElementById('changedfiles').innerHTML = message
})
```

**watchfiles.js:**

```
module.exports = function watchfiles(watchr) {

    // Import the watching library
var watchr = require('watchr')

// Define our watching parameters
var path = process.cwd()
function listener (changeType, fullPath, currentStat, previousStat) {
    switch ( changeType ) {
        case 'update':
            console.log('the file', fullPath, 'was updated', currentStat, previousStat)
            break
        case 'create':
            console.log('the file', fullPath, 'was created', currentStat)
            break
    }
}
function next (err) {
    if ( err )  return console.log('watch failed on', path, 'with error', err)
    console.log('watch successful on', path)
}

// Watch the path with the change listener and completion callback
var stalker = watchr.open(path, listener, next)

// Close the stalker of the watcher
//stalker.close()
}
```

**watchfile.html:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="watchfiles.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
        <h1 class="title">Watching files:</h1>
        <div class="watchfiles" id="changedfiles"></div>
        <button class="btn" id="start">Start</button>
        </div>
        <script>require('./renderer')</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding only the IPC communication this simpler version works:

**main.js**

```js
const { app, ipcMain, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const windows = []

app.on('ready', _ => {
  /* ... */
})
ipcMain.on('filewatch-start', _ => {
  console.log('Filewatch started')
  windows.forEach(win => {
    win.webContents.send('changedfiles', 'examplePath')
  })
})
```

**renderer.js**

```js
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

window.onload = () => {
  document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('click', _ =>{
    ipcRenderer.send('filewatch-start')
  })
  ipcRenderer.on('changedfiles', (event, message) => {
    document.getElementById('changedfiles').innerHTML = message
  }) 
}
```

**watchfile.html**

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./renderer.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <h1 class="title">Watching files:</h1>
      <div class="watchfiles" id="changedfiles" />
      <button class="btn" id="start">Start</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

Regarding the overall design, you can do the job of `watchfiles.js` in `main.js`, no need to separate them:

**main.js** (compact)

```js
const { app, ipcMain, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const watchr = require('watchr')
const path = process.cwd()
let windows = []
let stalker = null

const listener = (changeType, fullPath, currentStat, previousStat) => {
  var msg = ''
  console.log('change detected: ', changeType, currentStat, previousStat)
  switch ( changeType ) {
    case 'update':
      msg = 'the file' + fullPath + ' was updated'
      break
    case 'create':
      msg = 'the file' + fullPath + ' was created'
      break
  }
  windows.forEach(win => {
    win.webContents.send('changedfiles', msg)
  })
}
const next = (err) => {
    if ( err )  return console.log('watch failed on', path, 'with error', err)
    console.log('watch successful on', path)
}
app.on('ready', () => {
  [1].forEach(() => {
    let win = new BrowserWindow({
      height: 400,
      width: 400
    })
    win.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/watchfile.html`)
    win.on('closed', _ => {
      mainWindow = null
    })
    windows.push(win)
  })
})
app.on('quit', () => {
  if (stalker) stalker.close()
})
ipcMain.on('filewatch-start', _ => {
  console.log('Filewatch started')
  if (!stalker) {
    stalker = watchr.open(path, listener, next)
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks. I know you said only regarding the ipc communication, but the place where you send the ipc message in main sends the changed file path would be before the function to watch the files is started. 

Are you implying i should send an ipc message in the watchfiles.js when a file is changed instead of using the file watcher function to start in main and send the messages from there directly?

Comment: yes, separating `watchfiles.js` and `main.js` is unnecessary. I've added a suggestion for a more compact design

Comment: Thanks, implementing this now. If I wanted to add any other logic below that, wouldn't this block the main thread technically?

Comment: It is already async (as generally everything in nodejs), so unless you use sync functions in your future work, it won't block the main thread